# Can I test the add-in update process on a developer site

Tags: sharepoint-addin, update, development-enviroment

I am trying to follow the add-in update process described in [Update SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/update-sharepoint-add-ins) but on a developer site.

Where I got stuck is the point in the document that reads

> Then upload the latest version of the add-in **to your test site's add-in catalog** and update every instance of the add-in.

As far as I can tell, the "Apps in Testing" document library *is* the add-in catalog on the developer site. However while I can upload a new version of the add-in package there, there seems to be no way of updating an already deployed instance of the add-in.

Namely, I just cannot complete this part of the instructions:

> 1. After the latest update is uploaded to the add-in catalog, open the Site Contents page on the website where the add-in is installed and choose the ... button on the add-in's tile.
> 2. On the callout that opens, choose the About tab. On the About page that opens, there is a notice that a new version is available.

As there simply is no About tab on the callout that's supposed to open in step #2 - only Details, Permissions, and Remove. Could it be because the add-in was initially deployed from Visual Studio and not by using the developer site's "New App to Deploy" function?

Answer (score 0):

How to test a SharePoint app upgrade on an on-premises developer site:

- Publish the upgraded app package to a local folder and then upload it to the **App Packages** document library on the development sandbox. NOTE: It is recommended that you add a version number to the package file name so you then can easily recognize the appropriate package when performing an upgrade;
- Go to the **Apps in Testing** list by clicking on the list title on the development site's home page;
- Select the app to be upgraded (do not click on the app name as it would launch the app, just put a check mark next to the list item);
- Now in the ribbon above, click on the **List** tab;
- Click **Upgrade an app**
- In the popup appeared, choose the appropriate upgrade package you've uploaded on the first step and click **OK**